# Defragmenting using Defraggler made the fragmentation worse and increases "used space"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, disk-space, defragment

I decided to do a full defragmentation of my C: drive for the first time this day. The defragmenter I use is Defraggler by Piriform. When I analyzed the drive, it detected 13% fragmentation.  After that, I clicked the 'Defrag' button to start the defragmentation processes.

I thought it was going fine. At about 50%, it was 10% fragmented now.  But then I noticed that the used space increased from 86.3 GB to 103.2 GB! So I stopped the defragmentation. This was surprising.

After stopping it, I decided to analyze the drive again to see if the fragmentation when low. At my surprise, it went HIGH! From that 10% fragmentation, it increased up to 37% fragmented! I was shocked.

I went to Windows' built-in Disk Defragmenter to see if their analysis were the same. At my surprise again, it said 2% fragmented! I was shocked again.

I don't even know which one is accurate now. Defraggler or Disk Defragmenter?!? I don't know which one is the problem. Is it Defraggler or Windows?

Why did defragmenting make the drive more fragmented? Why did the used space increase? Should I try using a different defragmenter? Should I uninstall Defraggler?

Info:
OS: Windows 8.1, 64-bit
Defraggler Version: v 2.19.982
C: Drive Capacity: 185 GB

Comment: It is  already written http://support.piriform.com/hc/en-us/articles/204043974-I-ve-defragged-and-now-I-ve-got-less-Free-Space  To effectivly defragment a system partition you really need to do so offline (running operating system locked files). Offline means to use a seperate disk to boot from, or to use a boot-time defragger. otherwise your just about as well off with the windows one doing what it does.  for that partition.  For the rest of your disks or partitions that are not loaded with locked files it would be fine.  You should also have a backup of the entirety of any partition first.

Comment: Why use an external defragmenter on Windows 8.1? There is a task to defragment all drives in Windows 8, and if you let it run, there should be less than 1% fragmentation.

Comment: @Psycogeek

Sorry, but I really don't understand... I'm not an experienced user. What do you mean by using a separate disk to boot from or boot-time defragger?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik

Some people say that Defraggler does a better job than Windows' built-in Disk Defragmenter...

Comment: The files that are in use in an operating system, are the files that you have a tendancy to use :-)  If you have an offline capability to defrag then the whole partition can then be defragged, including the ones in-use.  The percentage of these files is not large, but they also are not going to be moving, to get out of the way to complete things. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qMld9.gif  this pic shows the locked clusters as red.  and the Partition is mostly OS (not user files), but a mostly trimmed os that has many things turned off.

Comment: @Psycogeek I'm sorry, but I really can't understand. Do you mean that I should defrag while not connected to the internet? I'm really sorry if I'm really asking so much stupid questions, but I'm not very knowledgeable about Windows. :-(

Comment: Should, i am not going to say should, because generally people do not care about it as much, and the hardware is way faster, it just is not made to be as important as it was.  Use your web search engine to search for offline defragging or boot-time. there are lots of programs, i myself have a dual boot capability, and use that method. I defrag while booted up to a different disk entirely.

Comment: I found this: http://docs.raxco.com/perfectdisk/12/en/Manually_Running_Offline_Defragmentation.htm

Is that what you're talking about? And what I really want to know is why exactly did defragging my drive make it more fragmented.

Comment: Sure perfect disk will do it, and it is a nice program. Fragment percentages can be all about how that is percieved, what you count, do you worry about large files that are going to be split, what about locked files you cannot change at the time. Is it based on size or Item,  Then start moving all that stuff around , or even doing a "reorder" which requires even more movement, and . . . well it has never mattered much to me the numbers.  The work has to be allowed to finish completly, and even then under all possible best conditions there will be some fragmenting left.

Comment: You should let the defragmentation complete to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

When you stopped Defraggler, it might have left some buffer data behind while it was trying to defragment a very large file.

When you analyzed the drive again with Defraggler, it counted the buffer data as part of the drive as well as all of the fragmented free space (you probably ended up with less contiguous free space after the partial defrag since it was prematurely canceled, so you didn't let Defraggler perform any of its proprietary optimizations).

The best way to resolve the issue is just to run a full defrag again (preferably on boot time), this time without any interruptions.